# Тире или двоеточие после обобщающего слова? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Допустимо ли здесь тире или лучше поставить двоеточие?
В первом случае перечисление и можно подставить "а именно", во втором тоже — "продолжать развитие", а именно "обучать".

Целей было несколько — достижение финансовой самостоятельности и желание заниматься люби­мым делом.

Необходимо продолжать развитие персонала — обучать управленческим навыкам, мотивации, развитию лидерских качеств, углублению знаний в части тех­нической документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно правилам, если однородные члены предложения носят характер уточнения или приложения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия ставится тире. В ваших примерах - уточнение, поэтому нужно тире. См.: Справочник практикум. Орфография.Пунктуация. Д.Э. Розенталь. Стр. 152-153

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, в обоих предложениях много грамматических  неточностей, желательно их сначала устранить.

Comment: О каких " грамматических неточностях" идет речь? Поясните, пожалуйста!

Comment: Например, в предложении 1 указаны две цели, но не несколько. Также желание не может быть целью. В предложении 2: нельзя "обучать... развитию лидерских качеств, углублению знаний в части технической документации". Но это мне так кажется. А вы считаете, что вся грамматика правильная?

Comment: Это уже не грамматика, а стилистика. Само предложение с грамматической точки зрения построено корректно. Да, с первым предложением согласен. Насчет лидерский качеств не уверен.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ошибки здесь более существенные, чем нарушение стилистики, поэтому я назвала их грамматическими. Но неужели можно обучать развитию качеств и углублению знаний? Всё это можно только углублять и развивать.

Comment: В первом предложении грамматическая (или логическая) ошибка очевидна. ***Желание*** не может быть целью. Максимум - мотивом выбора такой цели (вернее сказать - "подцели", собственно целью тогда стоит признать ***исполнение*** этого желания). Это никак не стилистика.   

Во втором предложении ошибка не такая заметная, но я думаю, что и тут она выходит за рамки стилистической. "Обучать углублению знаний" - это что-то из пособия для начинающих демагогов.

Comment: Грамматические ошибки - это неcоблюдение норм слово- и формообразования, норм синтаксической связи между словами в словосочетании и предложении.алоги́зм
    Алогизм  - это стилистическая фигура. поэтому здесь стилистические ошибки. По поводу предложения **Обучать углублению знаний** - согласен.